# Textfield is even empty but not considering as empty in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have some multiple textfields, And If all the fields are filled then only I have to call some method else I have to throw alert.

But, even textfields are empty, It is executing condition as false.

```
if genderTextField.text?.isEmpty == true && weightTextField.text?.isEmpty == true && heightTextField.text?.isEmpty == true {
                self.showAlert(withTitle:"Title", withMessage: "Fill all the fields")

} else {
 //call some function
}
```

But, If I print textfields text

```
po genderTextField.text
▿ Optional<String>
  - some : ""
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You should use OR, if you want to check if all the TextFields are filled

Comment: Your logic is wrong for a start. - you want `||` (or) not and - you want the alert if any field is empty. You can also omit the `== true` since `isEmpty` is a Boolean. I would suggest that you handle `nil` properly via a nil coalescing operator `if (genderTextField.text ?? "").isEmpty ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Swift 5.2**

A more elegant way to do it would be to create an extension on `UITextField`

```
extension UITextField {
    var isEmpty: Bool {
        if let text = self.text, !text.isEmpty {
            return false
        } else {
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

---

And then you check like this:

```
if genderTextField.isEmpty || weightTextField.isEmpty || heightTextField.isEmpty {
    showAlert()
} else {
    // do something else
}
```